# Ternary operator and Vue filters

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I've encountered a weird behavior in Vue. See the following `vue.html` code:

```
<label :text= 
    "$props.information ? (($props.information.primary || $props.information.secondary) | myFilter) : `No info`">
</label>
```

This won't compile, and Vue throws the following warning:

`[Vue warn]: Property or method "myFilter" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure to declare reactive data properties in the data option.
(found in Root)`

However, when I'm not using a the ternary operator:

```
<label :text=
    "($props.information.primary || $props.information.secondary) | myFilter">
</label>
```

It compiles just fine, and `myFilter` is found. `myFilter` is declared in `boot.ts`. Why does it throw in the first example? There is no difference in scope.

Answer (score 3):

A single vertical bar is the [bitwise-or operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators). Vue has done some special parsing to interpret it as "pipe to filter" in a binding, but (I surmise) only as a series of one or more occurrences at the end of the binding expression, not in the middle, as is the case with your ternary usage.

Comment: Are you saying that if I inverted the conditional, the pipe would be at the end and it should work?

Comment: I suspect the parsing would use the result of the conditional as input to the pipe. But yes, I think it would work, as long as you consider engaging the filter in either case to be working.

Answer (score 3):

The expression syntax is defined as `(JavaScript expression) + (prop | filters)`. Filters can only be appended to valid JavaScript - bringing in filters into JavaScript is not going to happen.

You can already use `$options.filters.myFilter(prop)` in JavaScript expressions.

Please refer here:
https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/5449#issuecomment-294337677

Answer (score 0):

Works for me:

> :text="`${props.information.primary ? props.information.primary : myFilter}`"

Other option is:

> :text="`${props.information ? props.information.primary ? props.information.secondary : myFilter}`"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).